# elastic search aggregation in java for all indexes in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to do query on elastic search by following the sql query and I want to implement same logic using Java API

```
select mimetype,count(*) from table group by mimetype
```

Now I have the following Java code but it does not return expected output

```
 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().setTypes("table")
                .setQuery(matchAllQuery())
                .addAggregation(terms("mimetype").field("mimetype").size(0).order(Terms.Order.count(false)))
                .execute().actionGet();
        Terms  terms = response.getAggregations().get("mimetype");
        Collection<Terms.Bucket> buckets = terms.getBuckets();
```

Please guide I am new to Elastic search.

**EDIT**
I want key and the doc_count for below json -

```
"aggregations": {
        "mimeTypeGroup": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "miscellaneous",
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key": "application",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "audio",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "text",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But I get only doc count not the key name in java - [image]

Comment: What did you get and what did you expect to get?

Comment: @Val updated!!!!!!!!!

Comment: change size from 0 to some number in your query

Comment: @kurt   still get same result.!!!!!!!!

Comment: the key name is in the `termBytes` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is an instance of `StringTerms.Bucket`

The `key` is stored in `termBytes` and you can retrieve it using

`bucketInstance.getKey()` and count like `bucketInstance.getDocCount()`

Answer (score 0):

Get key and doc count by adding this code with above -

```
for (Terms.Bucket bucket:buckets) {
            String key = bucket.getKeyAsString();
            Long count = bucket.getDocCount();
            listHit.put(key,count);
        }
```