# Elastic search query in java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to execute this sql query in java api for get elastic search data -

```
 select mime_type,count(*),sum(original_size) 
 from explore_object_metadata 
 group by mime_type;
```

I am able to get the data from elastic search for the following sql query -

```
select mimetype,count(*) 
from table 
group by mimetype
```

By the code in following link  - 
[elastic search aggregation in java for all indexes in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712140/elastic-search-aggregation-in-java-for-all-indexes-in-elastic-search)

How I get this.

Comment: Did you try using sub-aggregations, https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use aggregations for this.

- Use terms aggregation to aggregate by **mime_type** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html. Count for each **mime_type** will be calculated in each terms bucket.
- For sum(original_size) user sum aggregation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html as a sub aggregations of terms, to get sum(original_size) for each **mime_type**.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the ElasticSearch API to execute the CRUD request. the API can build JSON content with JAVA code.

Here is the official document for the API: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch

Here is the Maven config.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```